# WPF C# How to play local .swf file with a Control that still reacts to flow?

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

I'm trying to play a .swf file saved in the output folder, but the standard WebBrowser doesn't react to the flow of the document. It doesn't get cut off when it reaches the top of a Scrollviewer and that's a problem. I tried CefSharp, but I can only figure out how to play .swf files from the web. Are there any Controls that can play local .swf files *and* react with the flow.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I used with CefSharp to load the .swf files. Basically, it loads a blank HTML file and then runs some JavaScript on it to create the correct Flash object with the correct path. This works for websites, but I need to run a local .swf file and that won't work (probably because CefSharp runs on Chromium and therefore has certain security settings that don't allow files from the computer to be accessed like that.)

```
if (TotalChecklistBrowser[itemNum].IsBrowserInitialized)
                                {
    TotalChecklistBrowser[itemNum].Load(@"blank.html");

    TotalChecklistBrowser[itemNum].FrameLoadEnd += (origin, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Frame.IsMain)
        {
            args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.body.innerHTML = \"\"; document.documentElement.style.overflow = \"hidden\"; document.body.style.margin = \"0\"; var obj = document.createElement(\"object\"); obj.width = \"260\"; obj.height = \"180\"; var param = document.createElement(\"param\"); param.id = \"item01\"; param.name = \"movie\"; param.value = \"" + BrowserTitles[itemNum].Replace(@"\", "/") + "\"; var embed = document.createElement(\"embed\"); embed.id = \"item02\"; embed.src = \"" + BrowserTitles[itemNum].Replace(@"\", "/") + "\"; embed.width = \"260\"; embed.height = \"180\"; document.body.appendChild(obj);  obj.appendChild(param); obj.appendChild(embed); ");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: your trying and code samples please

Comment: @MaciejS. What sort of code samples would I provide? The only thing I can think of is how I load .swf files from the web via CefSharp.

Comment: you should provide code samples to fast and easly reproduce your issue.

Comment: Alright, @MaciejS. I've added what I find to be the most important part. I hope it's useful even if I don't see why the code is neccesary since it seems to be like it's just the CefSharp browser denying use of files on the local machine.

Comment: Are you just displaying an SWF only at full window size? Where does a _"Scrollviewer"_ come into it (do you have other HTML content like text / images / etc)?

Comment: @VC.One The SWF fills the entire browser window, but the CefSharp browser is sized down to 260x180 in the WPF and there's no other HTML content.
The scrollviewer problem isn't present with the CefSharp browser because it's a part of the layout. The standard WebBrowser, however, does not work as a part of the layout and instead lies above everything else.